# Alguem pode me informar o que está causando esse erro

Tags: php, mysql

o campo email no banco de dados é unique

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <?php
require_once("conexao.php");
$nome  = $_REQUEST['nome'];
$email =$_REQUEST['email'];
$telefone = $_REQUEST['telefone'];

 try{
 $conexao = new PDO($banco,$user,$senha);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_crud2 (nome,email,telefone) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$telefone')";
     $registro = $conexao->query($sql);

     $row = $registro->rowCount();
  if ($row==1){
      echo "cadastrado com sucesso";
  }else{
      echo "este email já está cadastrado em nosso banco de dados";
  }
 }catch (PDOException $e){
     echo "erro ao se conectar";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Como o @Leite falou, o problema é que você está tentando registrar um dado duplicado em uma row `unique`.

Você pode contornar isso checando se existe o valor antes:

```
$conexao = new PDO($banco,$user,$senha);
$registro = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM tb_crud2 WHERE email = '$email'");

if ($registro->fetchColumn() == 0) //Email não cadastrado
{
    //Código do insert, etc
}
else //Email duplicado
{
    echo "este email já está cadastrado em nosso banco de dados";
}
```

Ou checar o código do erro resultante. Quando o erro é por tentar inserir um dado duplicado em uma coluna unique, o erro gerado tem o código `1062`:

```
$conexao = new PDO($banco,$user,$senha);
$registro = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO tb_crud2 (nome,email,telefone) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$telefone')");

if (!$registro && $conexao->errorCode() == '1062') //Retornou erro de dado duplicado
{
    echo "este email já está cadastrado em nosso banco de dados";
}
else
{
    //Código do insert, etc
}
```

Comment: Péssima solução usando o select. O unique é justamente para evitar ter que fazer essa verificação antes, então não há motivos para fazê-la. Analisar o retorno do insert e, se necessário, o código do erro, é a melhor e bastaria somente ela como resposta.

Comment: Ah, só dei como opção, também não gosto da opção do select pq pode ter problemas com concorrência. O msm email pode ser inserido entre o select e o insert.

Answer (score 1):

A tua query deve estar a retornar `false`, que é o que [o `PDO::query` retorna quando a query falha](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php#refsect1-pdo.query-returnvalues), se estivesse a funcionar, deveria retornar um `PDOStatement`, que ai não acontece.

O problema pode ser o email ser repetido, se é `unique` na base de dados, mas com a informação da pergunta, esta parece ser a causa mais provável.

Comment: isso mesmo, quando o email não existe no BD e cadastra normal, mas quando ele já existe dá esse erro, porque  era pra retornar 0 e com isso executar o bloco else, mas eu não sei por que dá esse erro.